# Is there a Char collator in Java?

Tags: java, char, collation

I'm working on a small app which counts character appearance in a text and prints a simple report. It bases on a TreeMap. It is supposed to work with any UTF-8 (so far) codable languages. When I try to use the standard collator by calling `Collator.getInstance()` I get the exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.String`.

Is there any Char collator?

```
static Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

The TreeMap constructor can take a collator, but not for Chars.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream in = System.in;

    try {
        if (in.available() == 0) System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    count(in);  
    printMap();
} 


static void count(InputStream in) {
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))   
        .lines()
        .forEach(x -> tallyCharArray(x.toCharArray()));
}

static void tallyCharArray (char[] chars) {
    for (int i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
        map.merge(chars[i], 1, Integer::sum);
    }
}

static void printMap() {
    map.entrySet().stream()
    .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getKey() + "\t" + x.getValue()));
}
```

PROBLEM with compare

```
static Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(
    Collator.getInstance().compare(String.valueOf(c1), String.valueOf(c2))
);
```

This is clumsy, and it doesn't work yet. How to bind `c1` and `c2` with the map?

Comment: You could use `collator.compare(String.valueOf(c1), String.valueOf(c2));` where `c1` and `c2` are the characters.

Comment: Not that I know of. Consider using `String.valueOf(char)`,

Comment: What does *"app which counts character appearance"* have to do with [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) which is used to *"build searching and sorting routines for natural language text"*? **Collation** has *nothing* to do with **counting**. It's about **sorting**.

Comment: @Andreas Well, it prints too, so that that.

Comment: I added an update about `String.valueOf`.

Comment: @Andreas Collation is completely relevant here. As you said, "`Collator` ... is used to 'build searching ... routines for natural language text.'" The application here is searching for an entry in a map. Why are you getting hung up on what's done with the entry after?

Comment: @erickson But what is the point? To sort the result? To collapse "equal" letters, e.g. `a`, `A`, `ä`? Well, *are* they equal? If so, which one to you want to see? A `TreeMap` ordered by a `Collator` might map the three characters to the same entry, but the entry key will be the *first* such character *seen*, i.e. it'll be arbitrary what the key value will be, depending on the input text. That's just wrong.

Comment: @Andreas Sometimes that may be just what I want, sometimes I may think of using it in some other way. But the question is if it can be done and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

If you only want the `Collator` for sorting the result when printing it, just sort after counting. Much better for performance. See code further down.

If you want the `TreeMap` to use a `Collator`, get the `Collator`, then give a `Comparator<Character>` to the `TreeMap` constructor. Since you're using Java 8 streams, you might as well do this using a lambda expression:

```
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
Map<Character, int[]> countMap = new TreeMap<>(
        (c1, c2) -> collator.compare(c1.toString(), c2.toString())
);
```

Using that `Collator`, accents and upper-/lower-case characters are all merged. See sample output at the end of this answer.

**Full code for sorting after counting**

```
String input = "Das Polaritätsprofil für das Wort \"Hund\" als Testeinheit " +
               "könnte zeigen , dass verschiedene Personen unterschiedliche " +
               "Einstellungen zu diesen Tieren haben .";

Map<Character, int[]> countMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Character ch : input.toCharArray()) {
    int[] counter = countMap.get(ch);
    if (counter == null)
        countMap.put(ch, new int[] { 1 });
    else
        counter[0]++;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Entry<Character, int[]>[] counts = countMap.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[countMap.size()]);
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
Arrays.sort(counts, (e1, e2) -> collator.compare(e1.getKey().toString(), e2.getKey().toString()));
for (Entry<Character, int[]> entry : counts)
    System.out.printf("%c - %d%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()[0]);
```

**Output from sorting after counting**

```
, - 1
. - 1
" - 2
  - 20
a - 6
ä - 1
b - 1
c - 3
d - 6
D - 1
E - 1
e - 22
f - 2
g - 2
h - 5
H - 1
i - 11
k - 1
l - 6
n - 15
ö - 1
o - 4
P - 2
p - 1
r - 8
s - 12
t - 8
T - 2
u - 4
ü - 1
v - 1
W - 1
z - 2
```

As you can see, the result is printed according to German collation, with `ä` between `a` and `b`.

If you want upper- and lower-case characters unified, you should decide which you want in the result and convert to that, otherwise it'll be arbitrary.

**Output from using `PRIMARY` `Collator` in `TreeMap`**

```
  - 20
, - 1
. - 1
" - 2
a - 7
b - 1
c - 3
D - 7
e - 23
f - 2
g - 2
H - 6
i - 11
k - 1
l - 6
n - 15
o - 5
P - 3
r - 8
s - 12
t - 10
ü - 5
v - 1
W - 1
z - 2
```

As you can see, sometimes you get a lowercase letter (e.g. `a`), sometimes you get an uppercase letter (e.g. `D`), and sometimes you get an accented letter (e.g. `ü`). *That just seems wrong to me.*

Comment: Just what I wanted, thanks. Btw, a HashMap was slower than a TreeMap.

Comment: Why are the warnings suppressed?

Comment: Because I accept the warning and don't want to see it anymore.

Comment: There was a tiny bug in your code, which I corrected.

Answer (score -1):

A `char` is a UTF-16 formatted 2-byte value. Unicode symbols, **code points**, reach into the 3 byte range and in java are represented as **int**. So better use code points. An make a String from them as follows:

```
int codePoint = ...
int[] codePoints = { codePoint };
String s = new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);
```

Then collation is no problem.

By the way Character has many nice Unicode info:

```
String name = Character.getName(codePoint);
```

Comment: What does that have to do with the question? You're right, for full Unicode support, the map should be keyed by code point, but that doesn't answer the actual question about use of `Collator`. As such, this should have been a comment, not an answer. --- And I don't understand why using code point would make you say "Then collation is no problem". The `TreeMap` would still be ordered by Unicode values, not alphabetically according to some locale. Changing from `char` to code point doesn't affect the sort order, except for supplementary characters.

Comment: First, I'm not sure what I need a string for. I would prefer to stay on the Char level. Second, I would like to be able to sort the Char-keyed map along given locale. Is going into code points any help toward this end or rather a complication?

Comment: @tomas It is a problem if your text can contain characters from the Supplementary Planes in Unicode (*mostly* Emoji's). If your text has that, they are stored as two Surrogate Pair `char` values in Java, so you would be counting the individual surrogate characters, not the actual Unicode characters,

Comment: @Andreas Ok. Are they UTF-16? UTF-32? Java is UTF-8 based as far as I know. Will my program work with ALL Japanese and Chinese characters? How to fix this?

Comment: Java `String` and `char` is UTF-16.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. (1) One has to do the collator on the String. For instance in German `o, ö, oe` in words sort differently. Collators work on strings. So putting chars back into a String would be a solution too.

Comment: (2) Unicode is a numbering of symbols, code points. Binary formats for them are: UTF-8, UTF-16 (LE and BE) and UTF-32. Either format will do. In java char is UTF-18, hence String too, but in a .class file the string constants are in UTF-8. You will never notice that String has some encoding, as for retrieving/storing bytes you practically need to indicate the encoding of those bytes, and a conversion is done. This was a language design decision, that java Strings hold Unicode and can combine all scripts.